ordered schedule static in OpenACC
I am having code in Fortran which is optimised for OpenMP.
I want to check the equivalent call in OpenACC for following OpenMP call.
!$omp do ordered schedule(static)
When I searched on internet for ordered schedule static in OpenACC, then I am not able to find the equivalent call for ordered clause.
I just want to confirm it. If ordered clause is not there, then what is the alternative in OpenACC?

Sorry, there's no equivalent in OpenACC.  OpenACC was primarily developped with offload to accelerators in mind in which there's no method available to enforce ordered operations.
